# id from data-bind function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

How do I get the id from a div on a function data-bind?

This does not work:

```
window.APP = {
    models: {
        court_a: kendo.observable({
            court_a_touch_unit_1: function (e) {
                var id = $(e.item).attr('id');
                console.log(id);
            },
        }),
    }
};

<div data-role="touch" id="court_a_touch_unit_1" data-bind="events: { touchstart: court_a_touch_unit_1 }">
    <img class="unit_image" data-bind="attr: { src: images[1].url }" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
court_a_touch_unit_1: function (e) {    
    var id = e.sender.element.attr("id");
    console.log(id);
},
```

or if using data-id is easier, use this:

```
court_a_touch_unit_1: function () {
    var id = $(event.target).data('id');
    console.log(id);
},

<div data-role="touch" id="court_a_touch_unit_1" data-id="1" data-bind="events: { touchstart: court_a_touch_unit_1 }">
    <img class="unit_image" data-id="1" data-bind="attr: { src: images[1].url }" />
</div>
```

You want to put the data-id in both elements because the user could click on the image or the div.
TCGB

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers thank you; I am trying to add my knowledge to the stackoverflow hivemind and google searches

Comment: When adding your code to an answer or a question, dont use the snippet feature unless the code will actually work as added. You're taking `court_a_touch_unit_1: function ()` out of the object that it belongs to, it wont actually work in a snippet so there is no reason to use one. Also, if you do use the snippet, make sure to add all the required libraries, otherwise , again, there isnt much point in adding a snippet ; )